# Delphi XE7 IDE moves/resizes controls slightly when form is opened

Tags: forms, delphi

On opening a standard VCL form from our application, several controls are moved or resized slightly. e.g. a few pixels shorter or a few pixels to the left. Saving the form obviously commits these changes.  Anyone know what causes this and how I can stop it?

Our application was developed in Delphi 7 and I think this issue has started since we recently moved it to XE7. Having made various code changes to various forms we've started noticing that controls had moved/sized a bit and thought they were mistakes. But today I've noticed that it happens when the form is opened. The form was previously saved in XE7 (it's not just the first open of a D7 form).

The controls seem to be mostly losing a couple of pixels off the Height, Width or Left property. I've not seen any of these values increasing, only decreasing. Not all controls on the form, just a few. The problem isn't limited to a single form. The Form.Scaled property is false.

Is something getting rounded/recalculated? There are 2 developers working on the application - could a problem be caused by developing on different resolutions or something?

Thanks a lot for any ideas =)

EDIT! Viewing a diff of the changes that were applied, I think poss all of the controls adjusted have non-default anchor settings. e.g. a button moved 2 pixels left is anchored [akTop, akRight]. It's on a panel that is anchored [akLeft, akTop]. Another control that lost 2 pixels from Width and Height is anchored [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom]. I have just reverted the changes, changed the anchoring by editing the dfm and opened the form again: The control that moved previously didn't move. I'm certain it is related to anchoring.

EDIT2! Easy to repeat! It is related to the anchor of the control and the BorderStyle of it's parent control (TPanel). Add a form with a TPanel and add a TLabel within the panel. Set the TLabel to anchor [akTop, akRight]. Set the TPanel to have no bevel, CTRL3d=False, BorderStyle=bsSingle and BorderWidth=1. Note the Left property of the TLabel. Save the form. Open it again. Look at the TLabel's Left property. It has moved 2 pixels left. Keep on opening, saving and closing the form and watch the label move from right to left. [Here's a pic of my example form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPQoy.jpg)

Comment: Dont know if this is your problem, but opening a form in Delphi on a monitor with different resolution than the form was last saved in always garbled up our forms here.

Comment: Thanksalot for your input @GuidoG, I think now it's not related to diff developers and just the anchoring of the control and border style settings of it's parent.

Comment: I debugged this kind of issues in the past by enabling VCL source code debugging, setting a break point in the forms constructor / dfm streaming methods, running the application and looking what kind of "Feature" messes things up.

Comment: We have the same problem. We had it back in XE2 and now stil in 10 Seatle.

Comment: Thanks for that confirmation @diedie2